# Can I do raw TCP/IP over port 80 or 8080?

Tags: firewall, tcp

I have an application in mind which needs to communicate with an external (internet facing) "server".

The protocol itself is going to be really simple, and I was planning on doing everything over TCP/IP via Port 80 (or 8080) in order to hopefully pass seamlessly through firewalls. My "server" will be listening on port 80 (or 8080) for requests from my application. It will not actually be a web server (i.e. not expecting any HTTP traffic).

I have control over the network setup of the "server", but not the client environment. I will be coding both the client and server applications, so have control over those.

I have not really attempted any TCP/IP communication out of  a LAN environment before, am I missing something obvious? I suppose my question is more like this: my client app is going to be run on all sorts of customer networks, of which I have no access to. Is this a sensible approach?

I would be most grateful for any hints/tips/gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I think a better idea is to use http tunnel, because some firewalls will block non-HTTP traffic even if you are using port 80/8080.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really want to introduce anything complicated! Perhaps I should just use "proper" http commands in my protocol?

Comment: Yes, in case you want your traffic can pass most of firewalls